# pandas replace dataframe value by other columns value in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have this pandas dataframe

```
BU       |   DATA1      DATA2
01-TT        zone 01   noData
02-FF        noData    zone 02
....
```

and I need to replace the "noData" string by the corresponding row in the column BU, but only using the two first characters and adding "zone" word

```
BU       |   DATA1      DATA2
01-TT        zone 01    zone 01
02-FF        zone 02    zone 02
....
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for replace `True` values by `numpy array` created by [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
df = df.set_index('BU')

arr = np.repeat('zone ' + df.index.str[:2], len(df.columns)).values.reshape(df.shape)
print (arr)
[['zone 01' 'zone 01']
 ['zone 02' 'zone 02']]

df = df.mask(df == 'noData', arr)
print (df.reset_index())
      BU    DATA1    DATA2
0  01-TT  zone 01  zone 01
1  02-FF  zone 02  zone 02
```

**Timings**:

```
#[20000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)

df1 = df.copy()

def jez(df):
    df = df.set_index('BU')
    df = df.mask(df == 'noData', np.repeat('zone ' + df.index.str[:2], len(df.columns)).values.reshape(df.shape))
    return (df.reset_index())

def ed(df):
    cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('DATA')]
    df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('noData')), 'zone ' + df['BU'].str[:2], axis=0)
    return df


print (jez(df))
print (ed(df1))

In [219]: %timeit (jez(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 14.2 ms per loop

In [220]: %timeit (ed(df1))
10 loops, best of 3: 46.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: thanks jezrael. The problem is that I have more than one column of data. ¿Is there any way to do it without a loop?

Answer (score 3):

General solution:

```
In [135]:
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('DATA')]
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('noData')), 'zone ' + df['BU'].str[:2], axis=0)
df

Out[135]:
      BU    DATA1    DATA2
0  01-TT  zone 01  zone 01
1  02-FF  zone 02  zone 02
```

Here we first determine the cols that contain `DATA`, then we call `mask` just on these cols and using a boolean mask, replace just those rows that meet the condition and overwrite

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help EdChum!